# Sorting Two Combo Boxes Differently in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, sorting, combobox

I have in a form two combo boxes that have the exact itemssource property. Both combo boxes need to be sorted, but in two different ways. One is sorted by the ID (numeric), the other one by Name(Alphabetic).

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to sort listbox and comboboxes in WPF** 
http://www.kudzuworld.com/Blogs/Tech/20070815A.en.aspx

Since WPF does not provide a "Sort Order" property for its combo boxes, you need two different collections.

In the link I provided above, a commenter posted the following method using a ListCollectionView object to get a custom sort.  This allows a single collection from your data source to be used, while adding an additional layer of collections for sorting:

```
// Using System.ComponentModel;
ListCollectionView view = new ListCollectionView (channel.Members);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("lastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("firstName", ListSortDirection.Ascending); 
view.CustomSort = new IComparerImplementation; //Do this if you want a custom sort;
view.Refresh();
```

Comment: The correct way would be using a CollectionView over the ItemsSource. You could have multiple CollectionView, each with different sort descriptions, over a single source,

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Collection stays the same, read once from database or whatever. There would be two CollectionView client-side objects used as ItemsSource as an extra layer between presentation and data collection.

Comment: What I did originally (to have two distinct item lists) is that I hit the databse only once, but I made a copy of my first one. It worked out great.

Answer (score 2):

CollectionView is made just for that: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=38